# Как результаты передать в аргументы функции и записать их в файл?

Tags: python, json, for, filewriter

Собственно вопрос как и в заголовке - как результаты передать в аргументы функции и записать их в файл?

Результаты функции нужно записать в файл json. У меня есть функция :

```
my_string = '0123456789' 
def call_name(): 
    my_list = [] 
    for symb_1 in my_string: 
        for symb_2 in my_string: 
            symbol = int(symb_1 + symb_2) 
            my_list.append(symbol) 
            print(my_list)  


call_name()


# Функция чтобы записать в файл 
def write_in_json_file(): 
    with open(file_path, "w") as my_file: 
        text = call_name
        json.dump(main(), my_file, indent=2)


write_in_json_file()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте возврат результата из функции `call_name()`:

```
def call_name():
    ...
    return my_list
```

И потом его используйте:

```
result = call_name()
def write_in_json_file(data):
   ...
        json.dump(data, my_file, indent=2)

write_in_json_file(result)
```

Или так:

```
def write_in_json_file():
   ...
        json.dump(call_name(), my_file, indent=2)

write_in_json_file()
```

Comment: Теперь стало понятно, спасибо)

Comment: @user428968, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)

Comment: @MaxU , я новенькая на этом сайте, буду знать как благодарить тут)